# What does this translate to? ㄨㄞ

Tags: meaning

I have this on a shirt and cannot find out what it means. My findings are that it is bopomofo/zhuyin phonetic for "Wai1". The only translations I found were "lop-sided" which doesn't seem to make any sense, and "awesome power" which seems to make more sense for a shirt but this is a Cantonese translation and apparently bopomofo is not commonly used for Cantonese. Anyone know?

This is how it appears on the shirt:

ㄨ
ㄞ

Comment: Isn't ㄨㄞ 'wai1'?

Comment: Any chance that there is one more character above that? ㄉㄨㄞ?

Answer (score 1):

It is Mandarin phonetic symbols commonly used in Taiwan.

See:

1. http://lib.ctcn.edu.tw/chtdict/zhuyin_2.aspx?ZhuYin=%E3%84%A8%E3%84%9E&TopZhuYin=%E3%84%A8
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandarin_Phonetic_Symbols_II#Finals

When printed on tee-shirt in this way, I think it means something naughty, happy and enjoyable.  See https://zh.wiktionary.org/zh-hant/%E7%88%BD%E6%AD%AA%E6%AD%AA

Answer (score 1):

I think it means "WHY?", as a joke. Maybe...

**ㄨㄞ** not, right?